# Pandas counting column values based on name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
10  C   X   -
11  C   X   X
12  C   X   -
13  C   X   -
14  C   X   -
15  C   X   -
16  R   -   -
17  R   -   -
18  R   -   -
19  L   -   -
20  M   -   -
21  L   -   -
22  S   -   -
23  S   -   -
24  S   -   -
25  S   -   -
26  S   -   -
27  S   -   -
28  S   -   -
29  L   -   -
30  L   -   -
31  M   -   -
32  M   -   -
33  C   X   -
```

I have this data set and I want to count how many Xs for each letter value.

So for C I have this many Xs in column one and column 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert column `col1` to index, compare all another columns by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for boolean mask, convert to integers and for count is used `sum` per first level (here `col1`):

```
df1 = df.set_index('col1').eq('X').astype('int').sum(level=0).reset_index()
print (df1)
  col1  col2  col3
0    C     7     1
1    R     0     0
2    L     0     0
3    M     0     0
4    S     0     0
```